# can openVPN run a simple http proxy?

Tags: openvpn, http-proxy

I'm sorry for asking the shortest question on this website, but there's just not much else to it...

Can you make a simple http proxy with openVPN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

OpenVPN is VPN software, not http software. If you want to interact with http, you'll need to get other software involved.

Comment: Ok. Any suggestions to what this other software might be?

Comment: Please do some of you own research. After you've figured out a few things, come back and post a separate question. But keep in mind: we don't do handouts. We expect that you have done work on these problems yourself and have tried to solve them on your own before coming here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just thought "maybe this guy just knows some reliable software for this purpose". The risk downloading of malware is high these days.